# Laravel never ending EXEC

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, laravel-5, stored-procedures

I'm rewriting a program from pure PHP to Laravel and I have a problem with executing a stored procedure (I didn't write it).

When I try

```
$sheetLines = DB::select("exec XXXXXXX".dbo.PRICELIST '?'", [$id]);
```

It keeps on going while PHP hasn't reached max memory. (increasing memory only makes it run longer)

Meanwhile in the old program it takes about 3 seconds and sends the response.

```
$tsql = "exec XXXXXXX.".dbo.PRICELIST '".$id."'";
```

Also when I'm calling other stored procedures from other modules everything works fine.

I have noticed that something like this also happens if I try for example:

```
DB::select(count(price) from orders group by price);
// would work with: count(price) as price_count
```

I have searched this problem a lot but have found no solution.
I'll be thankful for any help

Comment: What is this `dbo.PRICELIST` thing?...also can you add the output of `echo $tsql;` into your question?

Comment: if you write the program again I advice you to say away from writing sql queriers all over again. the framework want you to focus on your code instead of writing queries for specific database platform  . the benefit from this approach you can change your database anytime you want ... specially in testing

Comment: I don't understand how a store procedure could have different behavior. The parameters are exactly the same? Not only on the aspect of data but on the aspect of type and size. Maybe the sp is missing some data validation and is thrown in deadlock. Could u provide some code of the sp (at least where inputs are used) ?

Answer (score 3):

I would access the underlying PDO driver to execute the stored procedure.

Try

```
$db = DB::getPdo();

$stmt = $db->prepare("EXEC XXXXXXX.dbo.PRICELIST :id");
$stmt->bindValue(':id', $id);

$result = $stmt->execute();
```

If that fails to work you could try the query method;

```
$query = DB::getPdo()->query("EXEC XXXXXXX.dbo.PRICELIST $id");
```

Regarding your count issue, in Laravel's Eloquent you can do the following;

```
$count = DB::table('orders')->groupBy('price')->count('price');
```

Answer (score 3):

I've little experience with PHP, but seen:

```
set nocount on
```

Cause oddball behavior in some MSSQL drivers. Especially a stored procedure returns a single recordset, but doesn't output a "(x row(s) affected)" type messages. (Messages can be seen when manually executing a query in SQL Server Management Studio.)
My rule of thumb for complex stored procedure is to add...

```
set nocount on
```

...at the start of a stored procedure and conclude with...

```
set nocount off
```

....just before the final output.

Example:

```
create proc spTester 
as 
begin
set nocount off

-- {... do lots of crazy processing ...}

-- ok, ready to return the final output
set nocount off
select 1 as colA, 2 as colB

end
```